# How to export more than 30K rows from power BI embedded javascript SDK

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am using PowerBI-JavaScript sdk and I want to export records based on the selections user does and call an API with those records. But I am not able to export more than 30K records at a time. Is there any solution/workaround to this?

code snippet:

```
visual.exportData(models.ExportDataType.Summarized)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        Log.logCsv(result.data);
                    })
                    .catch(function (errors) {
                        Log.log(errors);
                    });
            });
```

Comment: The solution/workaround to this is to read the data from the data source and eliminate Power BI as a middleman.

Comment: yeah, but I only want those records which are being selected by the user from UI using filters. how can I do that with the data source?

Comment: Use Excel or other tool instead of Power BI. Let the user connect to the data source, apply the filters they want, and fetch the data they want.

Comment: I can't remove Power BI as of now. Is there any way of some sort like providing an offset (to keep calling the powerbi api till all the records are fetched) or anything else?